# c++ -std=c++0x cause segmentation fault (boost logging)

Tags: c++, logging, boost, compilation

i copied a program from https://github.com/boostorg/log/blob/master/example/basic_usage/main.cpp. i renamed the main.cpp to mylog.cpp. at beggining I compiled it with -std=c++0x (detail is showed below). it was built fine but got segmentation fault when i run the executable file.  without -std=c++0x, program is running fine. pleae help. I am really new to c++, therefore, i may miss some debug information. let me know if there is any information you need to debug this problem. Thanks

note: i uncommented first three lines on this main.cpp

```
#define BOOST_LOG_USE_CHAR
#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK 1
#define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK 1
```

build settings from eclipse(in order to build this program, i think boost log library is needed):

```
make all 
Building file: ../mylog.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/home/help/usr/local/boost_1_54_0 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -MMD -MP -MF"mylog.d" -MT"mylog.d" -o "mylog.o" "../mylog.cpp"
Finished building: ../mylog.cpp

Building target: test
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/home/help/usr/local/lib -o "test"  ./mylog.o   -lpthread -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_log_setup -lboost_log
Finished building target: test
```

after built, I run this program and got segmentation fault.

```
$ ./mylog
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

use gdb. it points me to a library

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7100c0a in boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_value_set::find(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_name) const () from /home/fcai/usr/local/lib/libboost_log.so.1.54.0
(gdb) list
73      return strm;
74  }
75  
76  int main(int argc, char* argv[])
77  {
78      // This is a simple tutorial/example of Boost.Log usage
79  
80      // The first thing we have to do to get using the library is
81      // to set up the logging sinks - i.e. where the logs will be written to.
82      logging::add_console_log(std::clog, keywords::format = "%TimeStamp%: %Message%");
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7100c0a in boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_value_set::find(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_name) const () from /home/fcai/usr/local/lib/libboost_log.so.1.54.0
#1  0x000000000042713f in boost::log::v2_mt_posix::value_extractor<boost::mpl::vector2<std::string, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > >, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::expressions::tag::message>::operator() (this=0x7fffffffc6b0, name=..., attrs=...) at /home/fcai/usr/local/boost_1_54_0/boost/log/attributes/value_extraction.hpp:232
#2  0x00007ffff74c379d in boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::light_function<void (boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view const&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)>::impl<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::(anonymous namespace)::chained_formatter<char, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<2> >, 0l> >, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::expressions::attribute_actor<boost::mpl::vector2<std::string, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > >, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::expressions::tag::message, boost::phoenix::actor> >, 2l> > > >::invoke_impl(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::light_function<void (boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view const&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)>::impl_base*, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view const&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) () from /home/fcai/usr/local/lib/libboost_log_setup.so.1.54.0
#3  0x0000000000431b64 in boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::light_function<void (boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view const&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)>::operator()(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view const&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) const (this=0x652ab8, 
    args#0=..., args#1=...) at /home/fcai/usr/local/boost_1_54_0/boost/log/detail/light_function.hpp:444
#4  0x00000000004306db in boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatter<char>::operator() (this=0x652ab8, rec=..., strm=...) at /home/fcai/usr/local/boost_1_54_0/boost/log/expressions/formatter.hpp:157
#5  0x0000000000430806 in boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::basic_formatting_sink_frontend<char>::feed_record<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::fake_mutex, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::basic_text_ostream_backend<char> > (this=0x6507c0, rec=..., backend_mutex=..., backend=...) at /home/fcai/usr/local/boost_1_54_0/boost/log/sinks/basic_sink_frontend.hpp:440
#6  0x000000000042f505 in boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::basic_formatting_sink_frontend<char>::try_feed_record<boost::mutex, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::basic_text_ostream_backend<char> > (this=0x6507c0, 
    rec=..., backend_mutex=..., backend=...) at /home/fcai/usr/local/boost_1_54_0/boost/log/sinks/basic_sink_frontend.hpp:489
#7  0x000000000042d28e in boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::synchronous_sink<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::basic_text_ostream_backend<char> >::try_consume (this=0x6507c0, rec=...)
    at /home/fcai/usr/local/boost_1_54_0/boost/log/sinks/sync_frontend.hpp:145
#8  0x00007ffff7106053 in boost::log::v2_mt_posix::core::push_record_move(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record&) () from /home/fcai/usr/local/lib/libboost_log.so.1.54.0
#9  0x000000000041f8f1 in push_record (rec=..., this=0x651050) at /home/fcai/usr/local/boost_1_54_0/boost/log/core/core.hpp:308
#10 boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::logger, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::single_thread_model>::push_record_unlocked(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record&&) (this=0x7fffffffccc0, rec=...) at /home/fcai/usr/local/boost_1_54_0/boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp:268
#11 0x000000000041d2e6 in boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::basic_composite_logger<char, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::logger, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::single_thread_model, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::features<> >::push_record(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record&&) (this=0x7fffffffccc0, rec=...) at /home/fcai/usr/local/boost_1_54_0/boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp:582
#12 0x000000000041a9b4 in boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::logger>::~record_pump (this=0x7fffffffd170, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /home/fcai/usr/local/boost_1_54_0/boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp:279
#13 0x0000000000414de3 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd7b8) at ../mylog.cpp:116
(gdb)
```

Comment: let me know if i can provide more information. thanks

Comment: The content of `mylog.cpp` would be significantly additive to finding your problem. If it is as I think it is, you're program has undefined behavior in it, and as such the results will be as well. You're new to C++, and I can't imagine it is too large a code-list. Update your question with a code block containing that file (and any relevant user-implemented headers).

Comment: mylog.cpp is posted on the linker: https://github.com/boostorg/log/blob/master/example/basic_usage/main.cpp  sorry, i changed the name main.cpp to mylog.cpp

Comment: Ok, and when you run this (the build that crashes) under [`gdb`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) ...? Where does it claim the crash is.

Comment: no, i just run the executable file under command line. i got nothing but segmentation fault. ex. ./mylog    output: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: After making sure to compile with debug flags, try it under gdb. If all you have to do is run it to cause the fault, gdb will most assuredly assist you in finding the offending line (and the call-stack-dump will likely be very informative). This is an interesting problem, btw.

Comment: [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7100c0a in boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_value_set::find(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_name) const () from /home/help/usr/local/lib/libboost_log.so.1.54.0

Comment: it points me to a library.

Comment: if possible, paste *all* the gdb output from the fault *as an update to your question; not here in a comment*. Include a backtrace (bt) command output immediately after the fault.

Comment: i updated my post with bt. let me know if you need more debug info. thank you so much

Comment: You should paste a working command line how to build this stuff. Currently, this command does not even build it for me: g++ -lboost_log -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lpthread -lboost_log_setup main.cpp

Comment: @laszlo,  I pasted two working command, the first one for compilation and the second one for linking. the one you list is the second one. please read my post.g++ -I/home/help/usr/local/boost_1_54_0 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -MMD -MP -MF"mylog.d" -MT"mylog.d" -o "mylog.o" "../mylog.cpp"
Finished building: ../mylog.cpp  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem. Somehow, when I remove %Message% from the following line, it at least works. However, obviously now the log doesnt appear on console.

```
logging::add_console_log(std::clog, keywords::format = "%TimeStamp%: %Message%");
```

Change it to something like the following and you will see the results as expected.

```
logging::add_console_log(std::clog, keywords::format = expr::stream
        << expr::format_date_time< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S.%f")
        << " --> " << expr::message );
```